# Android List View Navigation

Tags: android, listview

I am a beginner and trying to do my first android app.

I have the following requirement.
When the user clicks on the item in the list, we should be able to navigate to a new page based on the item clicked.

Right now I have a sample code wherin I am able to navigate to only one page irrespective of the item clicked.

For exmple, When I click on football in list I should be able to navigate to a new page called by football class and when I click on basketball I should be able to navigate to a new page called by basketball class.

Also I want to add an actionbar to this listview.
I am able to create an actionbar with home, logout and settings option separately . But I am not able to add it to this list view.

Please suggest regarding how to go about this

Below is my code:

```
public class ImageTextListViewActivity extends Activity implements



        OnItemClickListener {

    public static final String[] titles = new String[] { "Football",
            "Basketball" };



    public static final Integer[] images = { R.drawable.football,
            R.drawable.basketball };

    ListView listView;
    List<RowItem> rowItems;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


        rowItems = new ArrayList<RowItem>();
        for (int i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
            RowItem item = new RowItem(images[i], titles[i]);
            rowItems.add(item);
        }

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        CustomListViewAdapter adapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(this,
                R.layout.list_item, rowItems);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }



    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {

        //Navigation to next page

        Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Football.class);
        myIntent.putExtra("Game",listView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());
        startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);



        //Navigation ends



    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use the position param of onItemClick method?

Comment: Yeah Thanks . Got it. It worked.
I am a complete beginner to programming. So couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Glad to help you then;) by the way I would be appreciate if you mark my comment as an answer. Thanks.